# Compare strings in r and create dataframe

Tags: r

I have dataframe with email and domain names, i would like to separate email address which match the domain and the one which do not match.

Say I have a a df:

```
email <- c('abc@kjf.com', 'jkl@def.com', 'ghi@kjf.com', 'def@kjf.com' , 'mno@asdf.com')
website <- c('http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.asdf.com')
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(email,website))
```

which results in :

```
> df
        email            website
1 abc@kjf.com http://www.kjf.com
2 jkl@def.com http://www.kjf.com
3 ghi@kjf.com http://www.kjf.com
4 def@kjf.com http://www.kjf.com
5 mno@asdf.com http://www.asdf.com
```

I would like to create dynamically 2 dataframes. one where the email's domain matches the website domain like:

```
> df2
        email            website
1 abc@kjf.com http://www.kjf.com
2 ghi@kjf.com http://www.kjf.com
3 def@kjf.com http://www.kjf.com
4 mno@asdf.com http://www.asdf.com
```

and one that keeps the non-matching, like;

```
> df3
        email            website
1 jkl@def.com http://www.kjf.com
```

I think i should use "regex" but i am not sure. Does anybody sees how this is doable please?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this, you can filter the rows

```
gsub('.*@', '', df$email) != gsub('https?://(www\\.)?', '', df$website)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Breakdown:

```
gsub('.*@', '', df$email)
###   .*   zero or more characters, followed by
###     @  a literal ampersand
# [1] "kjf.com"  "def.com"  "kjf.com"  "kjf.com"  "asdf.com"
```

and for the url:

```
gsub('https?://(www\\.)?', '', df$website)
###   http                literal string 'http'
###       s?              with exactly zero or one instance 's'
###         ://           literal string '://'
###            (www\\.)?  with exactly zero or one instance of 'www.'
# [1] "kjf.com"  "kjf.com"  "kjf.com"  "kjf.com"  "asdf.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column that identifies whether the email and website domains are the same:

```
library(tidyverse)

email <- c('abc@kjf.com', 'jkl@def.com', 'ghi@kjf.com', 'def@kjf.com' , 'mno@asdf.com')
website <- c('http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.kjf.com', 'http://www.asdf.com')
df <- data.frame(
  email = email,
  website = website
)

df <- df %>% mutate(
  same = (email %>% str_sub(
    start = str_locate(., '@')[,'end'] + 1,
    end = -1L)) ==
    (website %>% str_sub(
      start = str_locate(., 'www.')[,'end'] + 1,
      end = -1L))
)

df2 <- df %>% filter(
  same
) %>% select(
  -same
)

df3 <- df %>% filter(
  !same
) %>% select(
  -same
)
```